# Numpy vector/matrix multiplication works unexpectedly

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a problem with my code:
I want to multiply two "vectors" in the way seen below

```py
# what i want
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([2,3,4,5])
z = f(a,b)

z -> array([
    [2,3,4,5],
    [4,6,8,10],
    [6,9,12,15]
])
```

How should f be defined?

Comment: use `np.array` instead of `np.shape`

Comment: yeah sorry, mistake in the question

Comment: It's simple broadcasting ```a[:,None] * b[None,:]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.matmul` function on reshaped arrays like

```
a = np.reshape(a, (3,1))
b = np.reshape(b, (1,4))
np.matmul(a,b)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.multiply.outer(a, b)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html).

Comment: works aswell, but somehow results in an extra dimension
still thx

Comment: @TK36 Apart from the second dimension to hold the two-dimensional result, this should actually not produce any other dimensions. So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: By the way, `np.outer(a, b)` works just as well.

Comment: i reshaped it beforehand on accident, you were right

Comment: @simon I prefer `np.multiply.outer` to be more explicit about the underlying operation that is performed. It's a matter of taste though.

Comment: @a_guest I did not see it from that perspective, but this makes perfect sense.